# Backref in SQLAlchemy returns empty list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am following the documentation for SQLAlchemy, but I am not able to get the desired results. Can someone please point me what is wrong with the code

**Models.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()
class Employer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employer_table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    employer_name = Column(String)
    employee = relationship("Employee", backref="employer_table")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Employer : {self.employer_name}'

class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee_table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    employer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employer_table.id'))
    employee_name = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Employee : {self.employee_name}'
```

**App.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Person, Employer, Employee

# Create the engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Create All Tables
Employer.metadata.create_all(engine)
Employee.metadata.create_all(engine)

employer = Employer(employer_name="ABC Corp")
employee = Employee(employee_name="John")
session.add(employer)
session.add(employee)
session.commit()

print(employer.employee)
```

I just get the empty list. I initially tried it without `backref` to understand the `relationships` but it didn't seems to work with `backref` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code given, the `Employer` instance bounded to `employer` was created without any `Employee` instances added (e.g. via `append`) to `employer.employee`, nor was `employee` created without referencing `employer`.  A quick way to fix this is simply add the following line after both instaces were created:

```
employer.employee.append(employee)
```

Now running the following:

```
employer = Employer(employer_name="ABC Corp")
employee = Employee(employee_name="John")
employer.employee.append(employee)
session.add(employer)
session.add(employee)
session.commit()

print(employer.employee)
```

Yields this output:

```
[Employee : John]
```

Alternatively, if the employer was added first:

```
employer = Employer(employer_name="DEF Corp")
session.add(employer)
session.commit()
```

Later, an employee is created and then the employer of a specific name may then be queried, and then the id of the employer may also be assigned to the employee, then the same desired effect may still be achieved:

```
employer = session.query(Employer).filter(
    Employer.employer_name=='DEF Corp').first()
employee = Employee(employee_name="Mary")
employee.employer_id = employer.id
session.add(employee)
session.commit()

print(employer.employee)
```

Output

```
[Employee : Mary]
```